# How login works with REST API HTTPS (Spring)

Tags: spring, rest, vue.js

So I'm a bit new with REST APIs and web in general. I'm trying to setup Login using HTTPS + Basic Auth through my REST API. My front end is built with Vuejs. Lets say there's a login button that sends the username and password information (basic auth by the way) what should the API return in the response? I was thinking it simply returns "Success"?

tl;dr how to perform login against a Spring Boot REST API using Vuejs through HTTPS + Basic Auth?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For basic authentication you have to pass some key in headers to validate the user and then you can follow the crud to fetch that data of the user from database..since you are https you have to use keystore to authenticate the url also. It will return the role  of the user on the basis of the role you can direct the user to that page , the user can be admin , normal user or user from diff department. you can also fetch active user (whether the user is active or not )

Comment: sorry what will return the role of the user? Do you mean I should make a simple fetch for the user's role? I'm not sure why but I never thought of that haha.

Comment: the purpose of login is to authenticate and authorization of the user so if you want to skip authorization then you can just return success after authenticating.. But for standard case it should be have both ...Actully its all depend on the requirement of the application